# Has Team Fortress 2 sped up?

Tags: team-fortress-2

This may seem like an odd question, but have any of the general speed stats of TF2 changed?

It's been a while since I've played TF2, but when I had a game earlier tonight, it seemed somehow quicker, like in base movement speed and damage rates (therefore, quicker lives).

Am I just losing it, or has a recent patch sped something up? Like I said, I haven't played for a while, so it might just be my mind playing tricks on me.

Comment: It could very well be your mind playing tricks on you, but a good possibility is that the server uses a different configuration (as that is all editable on the server side (I LOVE THE HL2 ENGINE FOR THIS)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suspect this is a result of the settings of the Server that you connected to. (Assuming that you are playing the PC version of the game).

Answer (score 6):

No.  As DavidGrove mentioned, it may be a server mod.

Otherwise:
The Halloween event going on now has an effect that, when people exit the Underworld, they are Ubered, sped up, and do all crits for 10 seconds or so.

Obviously, there are also some new items that do more damage or increase speed:

The **Soda Popper** is a new Scattergun that does minicrits after a Scout has run around for a bit (to build a "Hype" meter).

The **Winger** is a new Scout Pistol that does 15% more damage, but only has 5 bullets per clip.

The **Liberty Launcher** is a Rocket Launcher that fires as fast as the Direct Hit but does the standard splash damage range, but it only has 3 rockets instead of 4.

The **Disciplinary Action** is a Soldier Melee item that make him and the teammate he hits with it move faster.

The **Reserve Shooter** is a Soldier/Pyro Shotgun that crits against players who are airborne and increases weapon switch speed.

The **Splendid Screen** is a new Demoman Shield that causes him to do damage if you get hit by the charge itself.  Additionally, if he attacks immediately afterward with his melee weapon, the hit crits (like the Chargin' Targe does).

The **Overdose** is a Medic Syringe Gun that makes the Medic move 1% faster for every 10% he has on his Ubercharge, but does 10% less damage.

The **Shahanshah** is a new Sniper melee weapon that does 50% less damage if he has > 50% health, and 50% more damage if he has < 50% damage.

The **Enforcer** is a new Spy gun that does more damage than standard Revolver, but makes cloaking take half a second longer.